# Android notifications grant and revoke access programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, android-notifications

I am building an Android app and I want to manage the notification displayed through the app and not using the App Notifications settings menu.

I was able to get the notifications status using:

`NotificationManagerCompat.from(it).areNotificationsEnabled()` and it works fine.

So based on the result, I set my switch to enable or disable state but there is no system action behind.

In case the `areNotificationsEnabled` return true, how can I disable them programmatically and same for enabling them.

I look at the solution to use

```
requestPermissions(NOTIFICATIONS_PERMISSIONS,
        NOTIFICATIONS_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
```

To re-enable them, but I am not it's the right way to do it.

Any idea? I cannot find any interesting things for disabling the notifications.

Thanks